# After migration can not access admin in Opencart

Tags: opencart

I have just migrated my e-shop from one hosting to another, after fixed config.php and php setting. The page is working, but I am unable to access admin page.

The error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method User::isLogged() in /data/web/virtuals/250608/virtual/www/admin/controller/common/home.php:685 Stack trace: #0 /data/web/virtuals/250608/virtual/www/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_front.php(83): ControllerCommonHome->login() #1 /data/web/virtuals/250608/virtual/www/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_front.php(37): Front->execute(Object(Action)) #2 /data/web/virtuals/250608/virtual/www/admin/index.php(167): Front->dispatch(Object(Action), Object(Action)) #3 {main} thrown in /data/web/virtuals/250608/virtual/www/admin/controller/common/home.php on line 685`

Thanks, anyone for help, I really need it.

Comment: I dont use vqmod that much.. but cannot remember if it has caches.. read up on the vqmod side of things..perhaps a cache refresh or something.
Secondly the error is clear it cannot find that one function.. did some files get corrupted if its an FTP transfer etc. USER::isLogged should be in the systems/library/cart/user...

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your answer.
I have tried to do migration one more time, admin area is now showing but after I log in there is only blank page. I have tried to change password through the form and it worked, so I suppose that database is connected properly. If you put in wrong username or password it won't let you in.

Now the only error is that I cannot see my dashboard.